# limited value in a File output

Tags: c++, filestream

I have a program that returns the execution time , the output of each run is diplayed in a file in the same row .

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math>
#include <boost>

using namespace std;

int main() {

std::ofstream file("MyFile.txt",std::ios_base::app);

v2 = rand() % 100 + 1; // just to burn  some time 
std::cout << v2 ;    // just to burn  some time


boost::chrono::duration<double> sec = boost::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
    file<<sec.count() << ";";
file.close();
  return 0 ;
}
```

After 4 run here is the output in the file  :

```html
0.0190567;4.92035;11.0541;13.1457;
```

I would like that after 30 runs the 30'th  result must be displayed in a newline . without any added functions or loops that will affect the duration of the runtime .I think that there is other way to format an output file via awk sed .

Comment: So you don't want to use: `file<<sec.count() << (counter++ % 30 == 0 ? "\n" : ";")`

Comment: instead of using a `;` always use `\n` and then use `tail -n 1 MyFile.txt` to print the last line

Comment: @WaeCo I would like to create a csv file , that s why I am trying to display 30 results separated with a comma . and trying to make the 30+X result in the second line and so on .

Comment: @NathanOliver doing a file<<sec.count() << (counter++ % 30 == 0 ? "\n" :  ";") will increase the duration of the execution , and I would like to test only the performance of the program . I d ratther  use a script or command line to copy values that overshoot a certain threshold  to new line .so this will not affect the duration time stored in the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk.

```
awk '{ gsub(/([0-9]+(.[0-9]*)?;){30}/, "&\n"); print }' MyFile.txt
```

This should insert a `\n` after each 30th `;`